# Is there any relationship between localization and completion of a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, soft-question, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $R$ and $M$ an $R$-module.

I've seen the terms 'localization' $M_\mathfrak p$ of $M$ and the completion $M_\mathfrak p$ at $\mathfrak p$ used with the same symbol.

My question is, is there any relationship between these two objects?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't write eloquently enough about these two to make a solution, but my impression is that they affect $M$ in independent ways. In commutative algebra you often localize, then complete the localization to get to the data you want. It sounds an awful lot like "zooming in" and then "image enhancing" although that might just be a colorful metaphor.